# Reducing dimension for Tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, vectorization

I need my vector size to be 40 instead of 50 when using "https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim50/2".

When trying to set input_shape = [40] it throws me an error.

model = "https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim50/2"

hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model, input_shape=[], output_shape=[40], dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)

How can I make my vectors of length 40?

Comment: The 50 here is referring to the size of the embedding vector.  The input shape is scalar (a string in this case).  The embeddings have been learned by this model, so I don't believe you can change them.  Since it's taking in strings and mapping them to the embedding space, the input is also fixed.  What you might be able to do is do some sort of transfer learning by using this as your base model in a non-trainable way and adding your trainable layers to it.

Comment: Indeed I can not change the size, so I will try transfer learning. Thank you!